# Rate limit error while creating openai embeddings

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model, azure-openai, openaiembeddings

I am trying to create openai embeddings for a large document. It is giving below error:

```
2023-12-11 05:16:20 | WARNING | langchain.embeddings.openai | Retrying langchain.embeddings.openai.embed_with_retry.<locals>._embed_with_retry in 4.0 seconds as it raised RateLimitError: Requests to the Embeddings_Create Operation under Azure OpenAI API version 2023-07-01-preview have exceeded call rate limit of your current OpenAI S0 pricing tier. Please go here: https://aka.ms/oai/quotaincrease if you would like to further increase the default rate limit.
```

I have tried experimenting with `'chunk_size','max_retries','embedding_ctx_length','retry_min_seconds','retry_max_seconds'.`

But nothing works out.

Any solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you sign up for the OpenAI API (rather than the Azure one) you can sign into the portal and preload a chunk of API credit, and your status tier should go up. Users who are using free credits are on the lowest rate tier, and get rate limited quickly.

Otherwise, you'll just need to wait for your API rate limits to renew.